# Was Attacked From

Tags: passive-voice

In this [paragraph](http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/european-leaders-step-up-rhetoric-against-russia-as-ukraine-urges-tougher-sanctions/2014/08/31/8e0d6ba8-30fd-11e4-a723-fa3895a25d02_story.html):

> Meanwhile, a spokesman for Ukraine’s anti-terrorism operation in the east said Sunday that one of the country’s coast guard vessels ***was attacked from*** a beachfront along the Sea of Azov that has become a flash point in recent days.

,is "was attacked *from*" poorly written?   Would "was subject to an attack *from*" be better?

Answer (score 1):

Whether something is well-written or poorly-written depends on the purpose of the writer.

This example is in the genre called "pro-government propaganda".  Its purposes are to make the Ukrainian government seem strong and fair and good and legitimate and trustworthy, and make those who are fighting the government seem dangerous and cowardly and terroristic and illegitimate and untrustworthy and inevitably doomed to fail.

In this genre, nuanced statements are usually poor writing.  Statements that can be interpreted in ways favorable to anti-government forces are almost always poor writing.  It is usually better to say "no comment" than to say something unclear.

By this standard, "was attacked from" is well-written.  It clearly blames anti-government (or "terrorist") forces for attacking "one of the country's coast guard vessels".

By this standard, "was subject to an attack from" would be poorly written.  It says the same thing, so it has no advantages in terms of truthfulness.  But it is unclear, it is passive (and therefore weak), and it does not blame anyone for the attack.

Answer (score 0):

> was attacked from

is OK since it actually happened. If you say:

> one of the country’s coast guard vessels was **subject to an attack** from a beachfront along the Sea of Azov

this means that there is a *possibilty* to be attacked, but has not actually happened yet. And as you can tell it is not past tense anymore.

See [subject to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/subject+to) also [subject to](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/subject-to.html) sense 3 or 5

Comment: If you are subject to *an* attack then that specific attack happened, if you are subject to *attacks* then you sometimes are attacked.